# React JS / Hook dynamic chat bot

Tags: reactjs

I have a static chatbot where I can display the messages through
but i would like to do something dynamic ie when typing or clicking the button i save the text in an array
good and i will also somehow send this message to my back end and then send a reply but I can't think of how to do that
that is, send a response to the backend and then the backend verifies the best response to the message
I'm not able to think of a solution for this, that is, by clicking on the button send the message and delete the message from textarea (clear)
and show in my chat body

logic code :

```
function ChatMessage(props) {
  return (
    <Styled.ChatMessage bot={props.bot}>{props.children}</Styled.ChatMessage>
  );
}

ChatMessage.defaultProps = {
  bot: false,
};

const Chat = props => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const handleClick = () => {
    setMessages(prevMessages => [...prevMessages, text]);
    setText('');
  }

  return (
    <Styled.ChatBox>
      <Styled.ChatHeader />
      <Styled.ChatLog>{props.children}</Styled.ChatLog>
      <Styled.ChatInput>
      <textarea  placeholder="........."  onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}>{text}</textarea>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
        className="searchIcon"
        icon={faPaperPlane}
        size="lg"
        color="black"
        />
      </button>
      </Styled.ChatInput>
    </Styled.ChatBox>
  );
};

export { Chat, ChatMessage };
```

presentation:

```
import { Chat, ChatMessage } from './Chat';
const ChatBot = () => {
  return (
    <Chat>
      <ChatMessage bot={true}>Hadsssssssssssi.</ChatMessage>
      <ChatMessage bot={false}>Helldaadssssssso.</ChatMessage>
    </Chat>
  );
};
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-torvalds-fyi77

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is, what you have tried to do to answer it, and what isn't working? Include the minimum amount of code needed to clarify your question.

Comment: But there is all the necessary amount of code

basically i need a dynamic chat a user types something and appears in the body of the chat and i send a request to my back end or call a function to check this message and send a reply

Comment: Basically I did the state to save the messages and everything, but I'm not able to make what was typed appear in the body and I also don't know how I would send this message typed by the user to my back end.